# Prove the modification of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-limit-theorems

[image]

I know we need to use some modification of the Central Limit Theorem here. But we can't use it directly because $(x_i)$ are not independent. I tried to substitute the representation of $x_i$ but I don't know what to do next.
Please help me with this question. Thank you!

Comment: What does "a sequence of iid$(0,1)$" mean?

Comment: Probably iid(0, 1) means independent identically distributed random variables with mean 0 and standard deviation 1?